# select list in visualforce component disappears after rerender

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I have an action function that calls an apex method. I have re rendered one of my output panel in this action function. On rerender the select component disappears from my output panel. Below is my sample code:

```
<apex:actionFunction reRender="opPanel" name="callApexMethod" action=" 
{!callApex}"/> 

<div id="deliveredDiv" class="position-absolute" style="margin-top: 21px;">
    <apex:outputPanel id="opPanel">
    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!!isPageReadOnly}">
        <select id="foCur" name="delCur" class="selectpicker" multiselect="false" size="1"
           <apex:repeat value="{!opions}" var="opt">
             <option value="{!opt.value}" data-icon="flag-icon flag-icon-{!opt.value}" data- 
              subtext="{!opt.Label}">{!opt.value}</option>
           </apex:repeat>
                                                
         </select>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>  
</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
         callApexMethod();
    });
</script>
```

The select component loads alright on load. However it disappears on rerender. The rendered condition is satisfied.

Comment: Its not clear on how the intended behavior is; when is the `callApexMethod` function called?

Comment: @Raul It is called onready from the js. Modified my code to add that.

Comment: Why is the `apex:actionFunction` being called on load, could you call your apex method from `action` attribute of [`apex:page`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm)

Comment: Due to some reason I needed to split the transaction, hence I've called it from js. @Raul

Comment: That is not a traditional way to implement such functionality, you may want to edit your question and specify why you want to do in this specific way. Otherwise this looks like [x-y problem](https://xyproblem.info/)